# Как закомментировать несколько строк одновременно в AndroidStudio?

Tags: android-studio

Можно ли в `AndroidStudio` закомментировать сразу несколько строк (если да то как), или надо вручную пройтись по каждой строке, ставя в начале `//`?

Comment: В коде `/*  */` или в разметке `<!-- -->`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно выделить строки, которые Вы хотите закомментировать, и при активной английской раскладке использовать сочетание клавиш `Ctrl+кнопка с ?,/.` (последняя клавиша в нижнем буквенном ряду) возле правого Shift:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если выделить закомментированные строки и проделать то же самое, то они раскомментируются.

Comment: **P.S.** Этот способ будет работать правильно только если включена английская раскладка клавиатуры.

Answer (score 1):

/*

*несколько строк кода*

*/
Таки образом можно закоментировать несколько строк.

Comment: Я знаю, что так можно сделать, интересно можно ли выделить эти несколько строк и нажать что-нибудь, чтобы преобразовать их в комментарий.

Comment: Можно, и это очень удобно :) Я написала в ответе о том, как это сделать